# RSpec requires me to print object before test can pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a simple model test where I am testing my validations and for some reason I need to print the object before my test can pass.

The following test fails (failed output shown below):

```
RSpec.describe HealthProfile, type: :model do
    let(:client) { create(:client) }
    let(:intro_hp) { create(:health_profile, :no_callbacks, :with_issues, client_id: client.id)}

    describe "should validate that" do

        it "diabetes is required in exit if present in intro" do
            exit_hp = build(:health_profile, :end, :no_callbacks, client_id: client.id)
            exit_hp.valid?

            expect(exit_hp.errors.keys).to include(:diabetic)

        end

    end
end

Failures:

  1) HealthProfile should validate that diabetes is required in exit if present in intro
     Failure/Error: expect(exit_hp.errors.keys).to include(:diabetic)

       expected [:weight_mindset_one, :weight_mindset_two, :weight_mindset_three] to include :diabetic
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[:diabetic]
       +[:weight_mindset_one, :weight_mindset_two, :weight_mindset_three]

     # ./spec/models/health_profile_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

After adding a print statement, `p intro_hp`, the same test passes:

```
RSpec.describe HealthProfile, type: :model do
    let(:client) { create(:client) }
    let(:intro_hp) { create(:health_profile, :no_callbacks, :with_issues, client_id: client.id)}

    describe "should validate that" do

        it "diabetes is required in exit if present in intro" do
            exit_hp = build(:health_profile, :end, :no_callbacks, client_id: client.id)
            p intro_hp
            exit_hp.valid?

            expect(exit_hp.errors.keys).to include(:diabetic)

        end

    end
end
```

Why is this occurring and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`intro_hp` is not instantiated in the first case, because `let` is lazy - instantiates objects only when it's used.

You can use `let!` to instantiate the object instantly:

```
RSpec.describe HealthProfile, type: :model do
    let(:client) { create(:client) }
    let!(:intro_hp) { create(:health_profile, :no_callbacks, :with_issues, client_id: client.id)}
```

On related note - you don't have to print it, you could just use it:

```
        it "diabetes is required in exit if present in intro" do
            intro_hp
            exit_hp = build(:health_profile, :end, :no_callbacks, client_id: client.id)
            exit_hp.valid?

            expect(exit_hp.errors.keys).to include(:diabetic)

        end
```